# How do I manage multiple combined index keys in Yii MVC?

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I have developed a script using Yii MVC and i have a problem with the index keys and criterias.

I want to prevent the insertion of a record that is already stored in the database;

My example, fails to check and tries to add a new record each time.

Why ? And how to do this ?

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '21-/popular/category/1.html' for key 'index_link'. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `categories` (`server_id`, `website_id`, `slave_category_id`, `link`, `name`, `image`, `videos`, `status`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4, :yp5, :yp6, :yp7)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `website_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `slave_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `videos` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_link` (`website_id`,`link`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_name` (`website_id`,`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=332 ;
```

the PK is id;
another index, is website_id + link;
another index is website_id + name;

the following code fails to check and prevent the insertion:
1

```
    $criteria_categories = new CDbCriteria();
                                    $criteria_categories->condition = " `server_id`=':server_id' and `website_id`=':website_id' and `link`=':link' and `name`=':name' ";
                                    $criteria_categories->params = array(
                                        ':server_id' => $model_website->server_id,
                                        ':website_id' => $model_website->id,
                                        ':link' => $matches_url[$value->link][$key2],
                                        ':name' => $matches_url[$value->name][$key2],
                                   );
$record_categories = Categories::model()->find($criteria_categories);
print_r($record_categories);
if (!$record_categories) {
$model_categories = new Categories();
$model_categories->server_id = $model_website->server_id;
$model_categories->website_id = $model_website->id;
$model_categories->slave_category_id = 1; //??
$model_categories->link = $matches_url[$value->link][$key2];
$model_categories->name = $matches_url[$value->name][$key2];
$model_categories->image = $matches_url[$value->image][$key2];
$model_categories->videos = 0;
$model_categories->status = 0;
$model_categories->save();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$criteria_categories->condition = " `server_id`=':server_id' and `website_id`=':website_id' and `link`=':link' and `name`=':name' ";
```

You have a couple errors going on. One is syntax. If using the parameter binding (which is a good thing to use), you don't want to quote the parameters.

That is, write `:link` instead of `':link'`.

The above condition also does not correctly check for existing records that have either of your two unique keys. Try the following:

```
$criteria_categories->addCondition("`server_id`=:server_id AND `website_id` = :website_id
AND (`link`=:link OR `name` = :name)");
```

This both quotes correctly and will find the record if either of your two unique keys match, rather than requiring both to match.